# Read the data from file in C++

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream

```
void Admin::searchFlight(string destination)
{

    int day, month, year, min, hour,flightID;
    string departure;
    double price;
    Flight sFlight;
    string read;
    Date dateOfFlight(day,month,year);
    Time timeOfFlight(min,hour);
    ifstream inFlight("Flight.txt");
    while(!inFlight.eof())
    {
        inFlight.getline(read,departure);
}
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<flightList.size();i++)
    {
        if(destination.compare(flightList[i].getDestination()))
        {
            //counter++;
            flightList[i].displayFlightSchedule();
        }
}
}
```

There is an error between `inFlight.getline(read,departure);`. Since my file got this type of details

(Flight ID: 1   Departure Place: Malaysia   Destination Place: UK   Price of this Flight: RM20000   Date Of Flight: 24/12/1993  Time of Flight: 12:12)

I want to read them out when I do this code `admin.searchFlight("UK");`

Comment: Please provide the code for `inFlight.getline(*, *);`.

Comment: Don't use `eof()` use the file directly (Is casted to boolean): `while( inflight )`

Comment: what do you expect the output of "admin.searchFlight("UK");" to be?

Comment: Where did you get the idea from to use `inFlight.eof()` as a condition in the loop? It is just wrong! You **always** need to check the stream after reading.

Comment: What do you think the `getline` loop does? Have you looked at what the parameters for `getline` mean? Why are there so many variables that you never use?

Comment: by the way, is there any others way to display out the details from file after I search the details? Then it will display all the details.

Comment: @molbdnilo means the getline cant use in loop?

Comment: @jefferyleo Of course you can use it in a loop. Have you given any thought to how and why you're using it in this particular loop? Where does the values in `flightList` come from?

Comment: @molbdnilo the flightList is from the vector<Flight>flightList...i use getline in loop due to i want to print all the date out from file which destination is from "UK"...

Comment: @jefferyleo That's the variable, yes. Where do the values it contains come from? Do you ever add any values to it? How is the `getline` in the loop connected to the data you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

You (incorrectly) read the lines in the file but you don't do anything with them. Your code should probably be structured along the lines of

```
for (std::string departure; std::getline(inFlight, departure); ) {
    do_some_thing_with(departure);
}
```

Comment: Kuhl my departure is just want to display out, the departure and others value I want to read from file when the keyword that I search the destination is match with the destination in FILE.

Comment: @jefferyleo: my point is: you just read through the file and you don't do anything with it. I guess, you wanted to insert it into the `flightList`.